# Python How to run a function with a variable name

Tags: python, function, variables, pygame

So I've imported a module from a folder "Games", but now I want to run it and this does not work

```
Game_Module=__import__("Games",None,None,Object[3])
Game_Module()
```

or

```
Game_Module=__import__("Games",None,None,Object[3])
Game=Game_Module.Object[3]
Game()
```

Can anyone help? I want to be able to call it without knowing what it is

Comment: Can you provide more information about what exactly you're trying to accomplish? The fourth argument to __import __ is a list, so when you pass that in, you can then access attributes of Game_Module using the strings in your list, but not using the name of the list itself. See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__) for an example of this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some list of objects you're trying to get from a module, you can do the following:

```
module_to_import = "datetime"
object_to_import = "timedelta"
list_of_objects = [object_to_import]
module = __import__(module_to_import, globals(), locals(), list_of_objects)
object = getattr(module, object_to_import)
instance_of_object = object()
```

You can then use instance_of_object as you wish.

This example obviously uses datetime as the module and timedelta as the object, but obviously you can replace these as needed!